# Wierd value from cookie javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have the following code

```
 if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
            if (cookie == '') {

                $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal().open();

                $('.team-option').click(function () {
                    cookie = document.cookie = "team=" + $(this).html();
                    setTeam(cookie);
                });
            } else {
                setTeam(cookie);  //Cookie already have value   
            }
        } else {
            alert("Cookie not enbabled");
        }

var setTeam = function (data) {
    var team = data.split(';')[0].replace(/team=/gi, '');
    $('.team-info').html("Logged in as: <strong>" + team + "<strong>");

    menuHandler.init();

};
```

The code simply sets a cookie with a value depending on which button you click when the modal appears. The value are then printed out at the page like this:
[image]

This works on my computer in chrome as expected. However, If navigate to the webpage on my colleagues computer, It looks like this:
[image]

What does this mean? Why Is this printed out?

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one cookie saved your saved cookie may not be the first cookie so you have to get the cookie array and split it and search for your cookie by both following names "team" and " team" because if it is not the first element of the cookie array you have to search for " team"

```
if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
  cookieArray = document.cookie.split(";");
  cookieArray.forEach(myFunction);

  console.log(cookieArray)

  function myFunction(item, index) {
    if (item.split("=")[0] == " team" || item.split("=")[0] == "team") {
      teamID = item.split("=")[1];
      console.log("teamID " + teamID)
    }

  }
  }
```